# Is WCF announcement the right choice?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have created a local WCF service with TCP binding. I would like to handle the case when my service suddenly goes down. I know how to check when the service goes down in client side but I do not know how to check when the service come back online.

In simple word, I want my client side to automatically create new proper connection when the service restarts.
After checking the internet, I found the WCF announcement feature, but I did not find a clear example on how to use the announcement feature.

Please note that the client connection object (service) is created automatically by Visually Studio by entering a service reference and not by myself.
My service has a static IP address and all the clients will be on the local network.

My question is that is WCF announcement the right choice or is there any other solution?

Comment: How about adding a healthcheck operation contract in your wcf service and pinging this operation from the client

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways general ways you can go about doing what you need to do:

Since you have a static IP address for your service, you can use the old method of having a "Check if online" timer event on your client side that starts when connection to the service is lost and keeps on poking the destination to see when the service comes back up again by calling a specific method on your WCF service that just replies `True/All-OK`
The issues with this approach are many:

- You need to have a way of changing the IP address on each client's configuration, which can create a maintenance nightmare.
- You will potentially hit your service hard if you have many client applications polling it every couple of seconds to see if it is up again.
- You will have a delay at to when the service is available again, maximum the duration of your polling interval.

So using the WCF Discovery method will be better because then your clients will wait for the service to come back online again, announce that it is ready and not congest the local network with unneeded traffic.
On the following sites there are examples and explanations as to how to use the WCF Discovery feature:

- [General WCF Discovery page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with the specific client side implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620626%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- An [Announcement example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483353%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the Visual Studio pages
- [Another site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/54db21/announcing-online-events-in-wcf-service/) with examples and a full application with config file that you can look at

Hopefully all those page are available in your language.

Comment: I try following [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/54db21/announcing-online-events-in-wcf-service/) that is I have added <serviceDiscovery/> in the <serviceBehaviors/> and also add the discovery end point in the configuration of the server.After that I create AnnounceService in the client side and subscribe the event but the event are not trigger not only when the service come online but also when it was disconnected.Any help is appreciate.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but here is my testing method. Before production , the service is created in "WCF Service Application" project type and does not host by IIS or any self-hosting method yet. I first try to run the client application then I try to run my service.The "OnlineAnnouncementReceived" event does not trigger.Then I try to force close my service.The "OfflineAnnouncementReceived" event does not trigger.Does WCF announcement service work even in case when the service is not properly close such as power blackout or sudden network problem,i.e does not close in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an announcement work , the server side need to add to add a  tag in the service behavior of a server side configuration file like this

```
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

      <serviceDiscovery>
        <announcementEndpoints>
          <endpoint kind="udpAnnouncementEndpoint"/>
        </announcementEndpoints>
      </serviceDiscovery>   

      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

and add a new end point also in the service tag of the server configuration file like this

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="TestService.Service">
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" name="NetTcpService" contract="TestService.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="NetTcpMex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint name="udpDiscoveryEpt" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://[replace with ip address]:8080/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

the main point is that end point we have added in the service tag

```
<endpoint name="udpDiscoveryEpt" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint"/>
```

And for the client side

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        AnnouncementService announcementService = new AnnouncementService();

        announcementService.OnlineAnnouncementReceived += service_OnlineAnnouncementReceived;

        announcementService.OfflineAnnouncementReceived += service_OfflineAnnouncementReceived;

        using(var announcementServiceHost=new ServiceHost(announcementService))
        {
            announcementServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
            announcementServiceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter to exit\n\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    static void service_OfflineAnnouncementReceived(object sender, AnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Service Offline");
    }

    static void service_OnlineAnnouncementReceived(object sender, AnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service Online");
    }
```

And the most important point is

```
     using(var announcementServiceHost=new ServiceHost(announcementService))
        {
            announcementServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
            announcementServiceHost.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter to exit\n\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

which actually start listening for the service announcement event.